# tomcat+html+form ошибка загрзки 2-й страницы (не правильно указывается адрес) - error 404

Tags: html, form, tomcat

из идеи проект работает отлично, если загружаю проект в корень томкета тоже работает отлично, а вот если деплою из менеджера проектов томкета и запускаю приложение по адресу **localhost:8080/app**, то при переходе на вторую страницу **localhost:8080/app/second_page** происходит ошибка.

На первой странице есть форма:

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" action="/second_page" method="POST">
  <div id="fields_container">
    <div>
      <div class="element">First name:</div>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="firstName"/>
      <span id="err_name" class="error"></span>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

`при нажатии на "submit" приложение перебрасывает не на **localhost:8080/app/second_page** а на **localhost:8080/second_page**`

мой web.xml

```html
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>addServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>addServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/second_page</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp</location>
```

Как мне можно решить эту проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста укажите ошибку в вопросе

Comment: Может Вы вручную скопировали jdbc драйвер в корень томката, там он виден. А из app не виден, потому что веб-приложения изолированы друг от друга. Надо либо включать jdbc драйвер в приложение (в `WEB-INF/lib`) или поместить в папку общих библиотек сервера (`$CATALINA_BASE/lib` или `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`?). Сложно придумать другую причину, если всё остальное правильно. А вообще, как сказано в комментарии выше, ошибку в студию.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я изменил вопрос, т.к. понял, что там проблема не в JDBC, а в том, что я не до конца понимаю принцип работы Tomcat. Будьте добры, гляньте, возможно, сможете мне подсказать.

Comment: @Sergey Изменил вопрос, подскажите, по возможности ответ.

Comment: Так ведь у Вас `action="/second_page"`, а это значит `localhost:8080/second_page`. Должно быть `action="${request.contextPath}/second_page"`. Все абсолютные ссылки (начинаются с `/`) на страницы  приложения должны быть такого вида, чтобы их сделать не зависимыми от действующего `context root`. Другой вариант - использование относительных ссылок (не должны начинаться с `/`). Если страница в том же каталоге, то `action="second_page"`, если в соседенем, то `action="second_folder/second_page"`, в родительском `action="../second_page"`

Comment: @Sergey огромное Вам спасибо!!!